# Managing Memory of NSMutableArray with NSMutableStrings

Tags: objective-c, macos

My apologies if this has already been asked and answered.  I am new to Objective-C and I am trying to create a project that contains an object with `NSMutableString` and I am creating an `NSMutableArray` of those objects.

Each of the strings in the object are declared as follows:

```
@property (assign) NSMutableString* propname;
```

In the initialization routine (initStringObject) for the object I am setting each of the strings as follows:

```
self.propname = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:16];
[self.propname setString:@"Name"];
```

There are a number of properties with multiple `NSMutableStrings`, a couple of NSInteger and a float. All `NSMutableStrings` are allocated with different capacities.

For the `NSMutableArray`, I am declaring that in the interface section of the view controller .m file as follows:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *objectarray;
```

In the loadview, routine I am initializing the array as follows:

```
self.objectarray = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.objectarray addObject:[[StringObject alloc] initStringObject];
```

The project builds fine but when I go to populate the view with the information in the object, the strings are corrupted.  The integer and float values in the object are correct.  I figure I must be losing the pointer to the correct location in memory but I cannot figure out what is going on.  Eventually, if I keep running the program, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error message.

This is an OS X application.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are not initializing the mutablearray correctly.

Comment: It looks like you're using ARC (since you're using "strong"), then the NSMutableArray is correct I believe.  @El Tomato what do you see as wrong there?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's the `assign` attribute in `@property (assign)`.  Use `strong` (the default) instead to have ARC properly manage the string objects.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to have fixed the issue.